# PDO update syntax difficulties

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a database with table 'comments'. It is containing photos numbered by id, number of likes and dislikes and a "pr" which is some kind of photo rank which is difference between likes and dislikes.
I echoed the PR and looks like it is counted correctly.
Some problem is with the PDO. I wanted to add it to database and nothing happens, no errors etc
What do i do wrong?

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename;encoding=utf8', 'login', 'password');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$stmt = $pdo -> query('SELECT * FROM photos');
while($all = $stmt ->fetch()){
$id = $all['id'];
$likes = $all['likes'];
$dislikes = $all['dislikes'];
$pr = $likes - $dislikes;

$stmt = $pdo -> prepare ("UPDATE photos SET ('pr' = :pr) WHERE 'id' = '".$id."' ");
}


?>
```

EDIT my first attempt:

```
$stmt = $pdo -> prepare ("UPDATE photos SET `pr` = :pr WHERE `id` = :id ");
```

Comment: Kind of offtopic but you should use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. This makes pdo way faster. I actually dont know 100% why, guess this has some to do with the dns translation but... try by your self, you will see :)

Comment: @dwza I'm pretty sure `localhost` will default to a socket connection unless `tcp` is specifically specified, so DNS lookup shouldn't come in to play.

Comment: Like i sayed, I dont really know why but I know pdo gets way faster like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put parentheses around the assignment. And if you need to escape the column names, you use backticks, not single quotes.

```
UPDATE photos SET `pr` = :pr WHERE `id` = :id
```

You should also use a placeholder for the ID, don't concatenate `$id`.

You then need to bind the parameters:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':pr', $pr);
```

Another problem is that you're using the same variable `$stmt` for both the results of the first query and the prepared statement for the second query.

The whole rewritten code looks like:

```
$res = $pdo->query('SELECT id, likes, dislikes FROM photos');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE photos SET `pr` = :pr WHERE `id` = :id ");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':pr', $pr);
while ($all = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $all['id'];
    $pr = $all['likes'] - $all['dislikes'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

But there's also no need to use separate queries for `SELECT` and `UPDATE`, you can do it all at once:

```
$pdo->query("UPDATE photos SET pr = likes - dislikes");
```

Comment: You are the most helpful person on this planet Barmar! thank you

Comment: @Barmar Assuming his original approach and assuming a single `PDO` instance isn't it also necessary to make sure all of the results have been fetched (or the cursor has been closed) on the first statement before being able to execute the second, or has that changed?

Comment: @Barmar Excuse me sir Barmar, I messed up something about this code. I just have edited my question adding what i wrote now but still nothing happens hmm

Comment: @LetMeLearn123: Did you pass the parameters to `PDO::exectue`? Also in your intial post you never execute the second statement is that still the case?

Comment: @prodigitalson I am trying to add $stmt->execute() but it says i didnt bound any parameters but i have no idea how to do this so far XD

Answer (score 0):

This is really an addendum to Barmar's answer with a more complete example. In terms of what I have to add it should be noted that you must fetch all the results  from a statement (or call `PDOStatmement::closeCursor`) before you can execute another one. This is on a per connection (`PDO`) instance. Doing this your code as is would need to look like:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename;encoding=utf8', 'login', 'password');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo -> query('SELECT * FROM photos');
$updateData = array();

while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
  // for each row of the result
  // create an entry in the $updateData array
  // we will make this entry conform to the format
  // expected by PDOStatement::execute ie.
  // array(placeholder => value )
  $updateData[] = array( 
    ':id' => $row['id'],
    ':pr' => $row['likes'] - $row['dislikes']
  );
}

// prepare the update statement
$updateStmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE photos SET pr = :pr WHERE id = :id');

foreach ($updateData as $params) {
  // loop over $updateData and execute the statement for each row
  // if you have placeholders you need to pass in the params
  // when executing the statement
  $updateStmt->execute($params);
}
```

Now with that said there is no need to do it this way as you can do it all in the query as also suggested by @Barmar:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename;encoding=utf8', 'login', 'password');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// query prepares and executes the statement all in one go
$stmt = $pdo->query('UPDATE photos p SET p.pr = p.likes - p.dislikes');
```

Comment: PDO is so difficult. I dont understand any of this code but it works, thanks XD

Comment: What dont you understand?

Comment: In mysql everything looked so simple comparing to this. All these strange variables, statements, executes prepares i guess i would have to buy a book to understand it all and thats what im gonna do probably.  What is p. ?

Comment: `p` is alias for the table `photos`... ie. `photos p` or `photos as p`. `.` is the way you access database, table, and column in SQL in an explicit fashion.

Comment: Thank you! i will give you + as soon as i will be able to